# ng2-translate in Ionic 2.2.3, the text doesen't change with different languages

Tags: json, internationalization, ng2-translate

I need some help with ng2-translate in an Ionic 2(.2.3) Application.
I followed this tutorial:
https://www.techdiary.io/internationalization-of-ionic2-apps/
and it worked.

I created an en.json file and a small "dictionary" as well.
The words I tagged with  {{"Example"|translate}} got translated to the related word.

But if I change my initTranslation() to "de" instead of en

```
initTranslation() {
    var userLang = navigator.language.split('-')[0]; // use navigator lang if available
    userLang = /(de|en)/gi.test(userLang) ? userLang : 'de';

    // this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't found in the current language
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
    this.translate.use(userLang);
  }
```

nothing will happen.
What am I'm missing?
I have created a de.json with the same words like the en.json file.

And is it possible to use the marked tags ( {{"**Example**"|translate}}) as default language? Or do I allways need to translate the tags now?

Thanks

Edit:
Clearly this one:

```
userLang = /(fr|en|es|in|zh)/gi.test(userLang) ? userLang : 'en';
```

doesn't work for me. It will only change the language if I change the default language. And it will only work if I use "en".
Very confusing.

Edit2:

Yep, if I use something like

```
userLang = 'de'
```

it works. 
But still, is it possible to use the actual html text as default language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//But still, is it possible to use the actual html text as default language?

You mean user browser language ?

if so, use this.

```
let browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
        translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|es/) ? browserLang: 'en')
```

else intially {{"Example"|translate}} Example need to appear later you need to choose the language? if so, add drop down to your html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li>
                      <a (click)="changeLanguage('en')">English</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a (click)="changeLanguage('es')">Spanish</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
```

.ts file

```
changeLanguage(lang) {
        this.translate.use(lang);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpfull ;-)